# use json data created via javascript with ajax.actionlink

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery, asp.net-ajax

I want to be able to post json data that was created via a javascript function through the [Ajax.ActionLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.ajax.ajaxextensions.actionlink%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) helper.

I am able to accomplish this through straight jQuery code, but I am going to be doing this in a lot of places and wanted to see if there was a more efficient way to do it within MVC.

Working jQuery code:

```
 $(function () {
        $("#delete-selected").click(function () {
            var ids= getSelected('ItemGrid'); //this returns a string[]
            var postData = { Ids: courseIds };
            var url = '/Home/DeleteSelected';
            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                traditional: true,
                type: "Post",
                dataType: 'json',
                data: postData
            });
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a script that uses unobtrusive JavaScript hooks like `data-` attributes to store the settings.

#### HTML:

```
<div data-ajax-url='/Home/DeleteSelected' 
     data-ajax-post-data='{function name or json content}'>
....
</div>
```

#### JQuery Plugin

```
$(document).on("click","[data-ajax-url]", function(){
        var postData =  $(this).data("ajax-post-data");
        var url = $(this).data("ajax-url");
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            traditional: true,
            type: "Post",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: postData
        });
 }
```

Comment: This of course will require refinement, but it beats rewriting the same ajax code every time.

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing an ajax call and want to update html with MVC, I would normally return Partial View from my call.Then update the html of the current holder with the result

Server Side

```
public ActionResult DeleteSelected(int[] Ids)
{
   //do something
   MyModel model = new Model(); //create object with new data
   return Partial("_PartialViewName", model);
}
```

Javascript

```
    $("#delete-selected").click(function () {
        var ids= getSelected('ItemGrid'); //this returns a string[]
        var postData = { Ids: courseIds };
        var url = '/Home/DeleteSelected';
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            traditional: true,
            type: "Post",
            dataType: 'html',
            data: postData
            success: function(result){
                 $('#MyPartialViewContainer').html(result);
            }
        });
    });
```